# karate dsl - running parallel features and scenarios

Tags: parallel-processing, karate, scenarios

in new release(0.9.0),I saw that karatedsl able to run parallel tests in scenario level (each feature will be breakdown into scenarios and run as 1 scenario per thread)..
so for example, I have 4 features, for feature 1 and 2 I want to run parallel tests in scenario level and for feature 3 and 4 in feature level(because of some case I have to do these things)..
so, are there any solution or suggestion for me how can I do it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Feature you don't want to run on scenario level you can add `parallel=false` tag to your feature.

```
@parallel=false
Feature:
```

Refer karate documentation for [suppressing parallel execution in scenario level](https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallelfalse)